# Laravel Mix , node-notifier, SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I tried to run `npm run production` but I got this error

node version : 14.15.4
npm version : 6.14.10

```
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

/node_modules/node-notifier/node_modules/uuid/dist/esm-browser/index.js:1
export { default as v1 } from './v1.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at compileFunction (<anonymous>)
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/node-notifier/notifiers/toaster.js:9:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/node-notifier/index.js:7:22)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-02-02T10_00_03_231Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ prod: `npm run production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-02-02T10_00_03_252Z-debug.log
```

Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the following steps to fix the issue :

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```